# How retain NESTED JSON structure in PowerShell while using the ConverFrom-JSON and ConvertTo-Json cmdlets

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have a simple JSON:

```
{
    "config": {
        "option": {
            "destination": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I read this JSON in PowerShell as

```
$flattended = Get-Content .\aboveJson.json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I need to set the value of destination element to some value and then save it back to the same JSON or another JSON while retaining the structure. However, while reading the Nested object I see, PowerShell treated the option element differently and while saving with ConvertTo-Json, I see the output as  `"option": "@{destination=""}"`

Could anyone please help and guide to any articles as to how PowerShell treats this data structure and what should be my way to handle the scenario ?

Comment: Ugh, that happens a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't see this issue with your current example. However, the symptoms you see are due to the number of nested levels in your JSON structure. By default, the `ConvertTo-Json` command uses a default depth of 2. You can manually set this differently.

```
$flattened = Get-Content .\aboveJson.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$flattened.config.option.destination = 'new destination'
$flattened | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```